# Access Denied Error connecting remote database using Spring

Tags: java, mysql, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I Know this question is asked a 1000 times before, bit non of the found solutions seem to work for me.
I'm trying to build a simple webapp, but when I try to implement jpa to save users and let user log in, nothing works anymore.
The application starts normal at first, but when visiting localhost:8080, my jsp's aren't shown.
After a while the application crashes.
The stack can be traced back to:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
Access  denied for user 'ufotje'@'%' to database 'hbo5_java'
```

I know the credentials provided are correct (I can connect to the db through datagrip...).

I Gues somethings wrong with my application.propperties, but can't figure out what.

My application.propperties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.date-format=dd/mm/yyyy
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://85.10.205.173 
                      /hbo5_java?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username=ufotje
spring.datasource.password=bd5296
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>be.intec</groupId>
<artifactId>pictureThisPictureThat</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Picture This, Picture That</name>
<description></description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        UTF8
    </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>required</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>Mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The error has username as "ufotje'@'%". Check where the extra "'@'%" is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Check if user is allowed for remote connection, run below SQL query on your database to allow your user to connect from everywhere.

Allow a user to connect from anywhere

`GRANT ALL ON *.* to <user-name>@'<ip>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>'`

Sample :-

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to ufotje@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'bd5296';
```

// grant root user to connect from everywhere(%) , which has root password.